# Detecting valid search parameters for a site? (Web scraping)

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape a bunch of search results from the site:
`http://www.wileyopenaccess.com/view/journals.html`

Currently the results show up on 4 pages. The 4th page could be accessed `with http://www.wileyopenaccess.com/view/journals.html?page=4`

I'd like some way to get all of the results on one page for easier scraping, but I have no idea how to determine which request parameters are valid. I tried a couple of things like:

```
http://www.wileyopenaccess.com/view/journals.html?per_page=100
http://www.wileyopenaccess.com/view/journals.html?setlimit=100
```

to no avail. Is there a way to detect the valid parameters of this search?

I'm using BeautifulSoup; is there some obvious way to do this that I've overlooked?

Thanks

Comment: The sites currently not working properly at present - not showing any journals at all (rest of page content seems OK though). There's no easy way to get it to show all journals (unless you can get the corresponding URL through the UI - eg. a "show all" link). The easiest way to do this is to use a loop to loop through pages 1-4 and run your scraping code on each URL.

Comment: @SweetBurlap haha yeah that's what I'll do; that was my last resort :( Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass any magic params to get all the links but you can use the *Next* button to get all the pages which will work regardless of how many pages there may be:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def get_all_pages():
    response = requests.get('http://www.wileyopenaccess.com/view/journals.html')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text)
    yield soup.select("div.journalRow")

    nxt = soup.select_one("div.journalPagination.borderBox a[title^=Next]")
    while nxt:
        response = requests.get(nxt["href"])
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text)
        yield soup.select("div.journalRow")
        nxt = soup.select_one("div.journalPagination.borderBox a[title^=Next]")


for page in get_all_pages():
    print(page)
```